# TSQL select into a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am doing a simple 'select' into a variable but not able to understand the output of second snippet.

Working as expected:

```
declare @tname as varchar(100) = 'F99Special_DMT';

select top(1) @tname = form_name 
from [dbo].[forms] 
where form_name > @tname

print @tname; -- output = F99Special_Physical
```

forms table has rows ordered by form_name. F99Special_Physical is the value of last row.

```
declare @tname as varchar(100) = 'F99Special_Physical';

select top(1) @tname = form_name 
from [dbo].[forms] 
where form_name > @tname

print @tname; -- output = F99Special_Physical
```

Shouldn't it output null?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. If the underlying `SELECT` returns zero rows (as will happen when using `>` the max value) no assignment is made and the initial value of the variable is retained.

You can use `@@rowcount` to check for this.

You need an `order by` to get deterministic results in the case that more than one row matches before the `top`.

```
DECLARE @tname AS VARCHAR(100) = 'F99Special_DMT';

SELECT TOP(1) @tname = form_name
FROM   [dbo].[forms]
WHERE  form_name > @tname
ORDER  BY form_name;

PRINT CASE
        WHEN @@ROWCOUNT = 1
          THEN @tname
      END;
```