# How to Modify a Value using stored procedure

Tags: sql, database

I'm new to SQL and I'm stuck. If anyone could please help me out.

I have a stored procedure `modifyMobileNo` to change a mobile number, where ID and MobileNo are the parameters. Change Sarah Furgerson's number to 3246568413

Table columns:

```
ID INT NOT NULL
FirstName NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
LastName NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
HouseUnitLotNum NVARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
Street NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
Suburb NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
State NVARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
PostCode NCHAR(4) NOT NULL
MobileNo NCHAR(10) NULL
DateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL
Gender NCHAR(10) NOT NULL
Ref NVARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE modifyMobileNo @ID INT, @MobileNo NCHAR(10)
AS
    SELECT ID, Firstname, LastName, MobileNo 
    FROM Table
    WHERE ID = @ID AND MobileNo = @MobilePNo
BEGIN
```

Do I need to add more parameters? Sorry, so confused.

Not sure where to start.

```sql
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Table 
    SET ID = @ID,
        MobileNo = @MobileNo
    WHERE 
        FirstName = @FirstName 
        AND LastName = @LastName
END
```

Comment: When using the tag `sql`, you should also do this: "Questions should **include** ..., and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used."

Comment: Freeby hint - you probably don't want to be updating the id column.

Comment: The database should know the value to sue for `@FirstName` and `@LastName`, on MSSQL this can be done like is answered here: [TSQL select into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018540/tsql-select-into-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

seems like it should be something simple like -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE modifyMobileNo @ID INT, @MobileNo NCHAR(10)
AS

BEGIN
        UPDATE Table
        SET MobileNo = @MobileNo
        WHERE ID = @ID 
END
```